# Guice - How to bind a type determined in a program runtime?

Tags: java, inversion-of-control, guice

SHORT ANSWER: to bind to Object instance bind() method should be provided with Class<Object> parameter. 
That said:

```
Class<?> type = got_a_type(); Object object = got_an_object();
// Illegal - compilation error because of type check comparing ? to Object
bind(type).toInstance(object);
// Legal and working 
bind((Class<Object>)type).toInstance(object);
```

LONG STORY:

I'm having json configuration files from old system in the following format:

```
{
    "$type": "test_config.DummyParams",
    "$object": {
        "stringParam": "This is a string",
        "integerParam": 1234,
        "booleanParam": false
    }
}
```

The test_config.DummyParams is the class available during program runtime and looking like this:

```
package test_config;

public class DummyParams {
    public String stringParam;
    public int integerParam;
    public boolean booleanParam;
}
```

There's some class which I want to be created by guice which is having constructor parameter (need to be injected) of DummyParams type:

```
@Inject
public class DummyService(DummyParams params) { ... }
```

Now, since DummyParams class is something provided only in runtime (through json config file) and can't be known at the time of compilation I can't use this type in guice bindings:

```
// Can't do this because DummyParams type should come from config file
Object object = ...; // Getting object somehow
bind(DummyParams.class).toInstance((DummyParams)object);
```

I have some old code which gives me pairs of Class and Object (type and instance) read from all json config files:

```
class ConfigObject { 
    Class<?> type;
    Object instance;
}
```

I have tried simply to bind them:

```
ConfigObject obj = config.read(); // Getting pairs from config files walker
bind(obj.type).toInstance(obj.instance);
```

But this isn't compilable: "java: toInstance(capture#189 of ?) in com.google.inject.binder.LinkedBindingBuilder cannot be applied to (java.lang.Object)".

So here's a question: how to bind the instance of a type which is determined in the runtime? Am I breaking IoC concepts and shouln'd be doing what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can safely use typecasts here. Here is a complete example:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Holder holder = new Holder("abcd", String.class);

        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new AbstractModule() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bind((Class<Object>) holder.type).toInstance(holder.instance);
            }
        });

        System.out.println(injector.getInstance(String.class));  // Prints "abcd"
    }

    public static class Holder {
        public final Class<?> type;
        public final Object instance;

        public Holder(Object instance, Class<?> type) {
            this.instance = instance;
            this.type = type;
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can move the problem to the upper level and change your config object to contain `Class<Object>`; then you will have to cast the class in your config reader:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Holder holder = new Holder("abcd", (Class<Object>) (Class<?>) String.class);

        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new AbstractModule() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bind(holder.type).toInstance(holder.instance);
            }
        });

        System.out.println(injector.getInstance(String.class));
    }

    public static class Holder {
        public final Class<Object> type;
        public final Object instance;

        public Holder(Object instance, Class<Object> type) {
            this.instance = instance;
            this.type = type;
        }
    }
}
```

This will require casting through a wildcard type or something like this, though.

However, the whole situation is really strange. If your configuration classes do not have common supertype, how they will be used at all? If you do not know in advance which class your object belongs to, you cannot (almost) use it without reflection or `instanceof`s.

Answer (score 1):

Using and abusing of raw types, implicit unchecked casts and some guava libraries:

```
public class RuntimeParams {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {

    // reads from config and bind in runtime
    final ConfigReader config = new ConfigReader();
    final ConfigObject configObject = config.read();
    final Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new AbstractModule() {
      @Override protected void configure() {
        bind(configObject.type).toInstance(configObject.instance);
      }
    });

    // use the binded instance
    final DummyParams instance = injector.getInstance(DummyParams.class);
    System.out.println("DummyParams' stringParam: " + instance.stringParam + "\nDummyParams' integerParam: "
        + instance.integerParam + "\nDummyParams' booleanParam: " + instance.booleanParam);
  }
}

class ConfigObject<T> {
  private static final Gson gson = new Gson();

  final T instance;
  final Class<T> type;

  ConfigObject(final String json, final Class<T> type) {
    this.instance = gson.fromJson(json, type);
    this.type = type;
  }
}

class ConfigReader {
  private static final Gson gson = new Gson();

  ConfigObject read() throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
    try (final FileReader reader = new FileReader(new File("src/main/resources/runtimeClazzNParams.json"));) {
      final Map<String, Object> configMap = gson.fromJson(reader, Types.mapOf(String.class, Object.class));
      final Class<?> clazz = Class.forName((String) configMap.get("$type"));
      return new ConfigObject<>(gson.toJson(configMap.get("$object")), clazz);
    }
  }
}
```

It is similar to Vladimir's solution, but with the casts implicit and raw types instead of direct Object references.

I also wrote a new way of parsing the JSON using the Gson guava class methods.